# En Laravel 5.2, ¿Cómo logro la redirección correcta a la página de inicio después de haberme autenticado?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Le saludo a todos, e intentado personalizar un poco la autenticación que Laravel proporciona después de usar el comando:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

He modificado el archivo auth.php:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'ctrl_usuarios',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'ctrl_usuarios' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class
    ],
],
```

Eso debería estar bien. También modifiqué el Modelo:

```
protected $table = "ctrl_usuarios";
protected $primaryKey = 'id_usuario';
protected $fillable = [
    'id_usuario', 'email', 'password',
];
public static $rules = array(
    'email' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required'
);

public $timestamps = false;
```

De igual forma, personalicé el trait `AuthenticareUsers` y lo he puesto en el `namespace` que se ve enseguida:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard as Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use App\Http\Requests\AuthRequest as Request;

trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware("guest", ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    public function login(Request $request, Auth $auth){
        $authotized = $auth->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));
        if ($authotized){
            return redirect('/inicio');
        }

        return back()->
            with('authError', 'Email o contraseña incorrectos')->
            withInput($request->except('password'));
    }

    public function logout (Auth $auth){
        $auth->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Por supuesto que en el `AuthController` estoy haciendo referencia al nuevo `AuthenticateUsers`. El contenido también lo modifiqué de esta forma:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}

public function index() {
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

Sobre el archivo routes.php, a quedado así:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['middleware'=> 'auth', 'uses' =>'HomeController@index']);
    Route::get('inicio', ['middleware'=> ['auth'], 'uses' =>'HomeController@index']);

    Route::get('acceso', 'Auth\AuthController@index');
    Route::post('acceso', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('cerrarsesion', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

});
```

De los Middleware solo cambié las rutas destino.

Lo anterior ha sido modificado tal cual. trato de recuperar el valor de `Auth` dentro de `AuthenticateUsers` (después de enviar el formulario de login) tengo el siguiente resultado:

```
SessionGuard {#166 ▼
#name: "web"
#lastAttempted: User {#198 ▶}
#viaRemember: false
#session: Store {#134 ▶}
#cookie: CookieJar {#133 ▶}
#request: Request {#40 ▶}
#events: Dispatcher {#5 ▶}
#loggedOut: false
#tokenRetrievalAttempted: false
#user: User {#198 ▼
#table: "ctrl_usuarios"
#primaryKey: "id_usuario"
#fillable: array:3 [▶]
+timestamps: false
#connection: null
#perPage: 15
+incrementing: true
#attributes: array:8 [▶]
#original: array:8 [▶]
#relations: []
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#appends: []
#guarded: array:1 [▶]
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#casts: []
#touches: []
#observables: []
#with: []
#morphClass: null
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
#provider: EloquentUserProvider {#162 ▶}
}
```

Lo cual me da a entender que el usuario está correctamente logueado, pero parece que no se ha guardado la sesión, por lo que al momento de direccionar a:

```
return redirect('/inicio');
```

no lo hace. El controlador de esa ruta es `HomeController`, y usa el método `index()`. El contenido de ese método Index es:

```
return view('/inicio');
```

Y finalmente el contructor de `HomeController` tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

He tratado de hacer el trabajo lo más completo posible, pero no veo los resultados correctos de la redirección, No sé que estaría haciendo mal, le agradecería cualquier ayuda que me pueda orientar a la solución de este problema.

Comment: qué tipo de driver de sesión está usando?

Comment: Estoy usando Eloquent :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como se describe en la documentación de laravel 5.2 debes establecer la propiedad redirectTo en tu AuthController:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

en caso de login correcto redirige a "home", en caso contrario redirige al formulario de login de nuevo.

No entiendo para que el `return redirect('/inicio');` dentro de AuthenticatesUsers si ya tienes `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` en el 
AuthController, probablemente el trait AuthenticatesUsers sea el problema,   yo usaría el de laravel.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
```

También deberías revisar el Kernel.php y verificar que los grupos middleware sean correctos, debería ser algo así:

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
```

Comment: Está establecida ahí, de la misma forma :(

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo hago de una manera muy sencilla crear un `AuthController` nuevo y no utilizar el que crea por defecto [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel).

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'    => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    if (!auth()->attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']))) {
        return redirect()->route('auth_show_path')->withErrors('No encontramos al usuario.');
    }
    return redirect()->intended('/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo mi script donde tengo mi propio métodos de autentificación

Controlador de autenficiación:

```
public function getLogin()
  {
    $data['title'] = "Login";
    return view('plataforma.login',$data);
  }

public function postLogear(Request $request)
  {
    //Mensaje de error
    $messages = [
      'required' => ':Attribute es requerido',
    ];
    //Reglas de validación
    $rules = [
      'email' => 'required',
      'password' => 'required',
    ];
    //Valido los campos
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules,$messages);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
      return redirect('plataforma/login')
      ->withErrors($validator)
      ->withInput();
    }
    //Condiciones para la consulta sql
    $where = ['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password];
    $administrador = administrador::where($where)->find(1);
    //Si el usuario no existe en la base de datos, redireccionará a la vista login
    if($administrador == null)
    {
      return redirect('plataforma/login')
      ->withErrors(array("messages"=>"Datos incorrectos"))
      ->withInput();
    }else{
      //Si el usuario existe, creo las variables de sesión que se utilizarán para validar el ingreso
      $request->session()->put('sesionAdministrador', true);
      $request->session()->put('nombreUsuario', $administrador->nombre);
      $request->session()->put('apellidoUsuario', $administrador->apellido);
      $request->session()->put('idUsuario', $administrador->id);
      return redirect('plataforma/principal');
    }
  }
```

La vista de formulario en blade sería:

```
<form action="logear" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <button class="btn btn-info btn-block">Ingresar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

y el middleware sería el siguiente:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if ($request->session()->get('sesionAdministrador') == null) {
      return redirect('plataforma/login');
    }

    return $next($request);
  }
```

Saludos !

Answer (score 1):

Revisaste que no exista conflicto en las rutas que estas definiendo, según lo que compartiste de código estas dos rutas usan en mismo método(index()) del controlador:

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware'=> 'auth', 'uses' =>'HomeController@index']);
Route::get('inicio', ['middleware'=> ['auth'], 'uses' =>'HomeController@index']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tiene razón [Ivan G Domenech](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3379/250) en el controlador está ubicado en `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{


    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';  /*Aqui tienes que modificar 
                                   la ruta a donde quieres redirigir una vez autenticado*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto es para retornar a la direcion anterior a la autenticación que se hizo.

```
class FacebookController extends Controller{

public function redirectToProvider(){
    Session::flash('url', URL::previous());
    return \Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback(){
    $user = \Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    return Redirect::to(Session::get('url'));  
}
}
```

Si deseas a la pagina de inicio solo cambia la linea:

```
return Redirect::to('/inicio');
```

Answer (score 1):

app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

//en esta parte configuras a donde quieres que te lleve una vez autentificado

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/miruta');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para redireccionar en laravel 5.4

```
href="{{ url('/') }}"
```

Comment: Hola @Legendario. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte. ¿Podrías explicar con un poco más de detalle sobre cómo es que de esa forma se responde a la pregunta? Probablemente encuentres útil lov que se describe en [answers].